# Why does onChange crash Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, crash

We just released an online shop.

On this page the selectboxes crashes Internet Explorer 7 on some computers. Never on my computer.
Does anybody knows why?

Live link: <strike>http://velour.se/collection/women/tops/eloise</strike>
Update: turns out that the first like I posted did not crash.
But the following does: http://velour.se/collection/women/outerwear/irina

Screendump: http://skitch.com/jesperlind/nc4j2/tops-eloise-velour-ie7-bug

**Original version:**

```
<select id="sizeDD" onchange="javascript:SizeChange(this);"></select>

//Internet Explorer problem.
function SizeChange(e){
    DrawAmountDD(GetAmountById(e.value));
}
```

Here's a bit of the code I think might be involved:

```
    function DrawAmountDD(maxAmount){
        /*var max = parseInt(maxAmount) > parseInt(maxShowAmount) ? maxShowAmount : maxAmount;
        var html = "";
        for(var i=1; i <= max; i++){
            html += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
        }
        $("#amountDD").html(html);*/

        var max = parseInt(maxAmount) > parseInt(maxShowAmount) ? maxShowAmount : maxAmount;
        var ddlAmount = document.getElementById("amountDD");
        ddlAmount.length=max;

        for(var a=1; a <= max; a++){
            ddlAmount.options[a-1].value = a;
            ddlAmount.options[a-1].text = a;
        }
    }
```

Version 2:

```
<select id="sizeDD"></select>
<select id="amountDD"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxShowAmount = '5';
    var colorSizeArr =
      { "colSize":
        [
            { "color": "Black/Offwhite",
              "specificId": "2",
              "size": "XS",
              "amount": "1" }
        ]
      };

    colorSizeArr.colSize.push(
      { "color": "Black/Offwhite",
        "specificId": "13",
        "size": "S",
        "amount": "2" });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectSizeDD = document.getElementById('sizeDD');
        selectSizeDD.onchange = function () { sizeChange(selectSizeDD); };
    });

    function sizeChange(e) {
        DrawAmountDD(GetAmountById(e.value));
    }

    function GetAmountById(specificId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < colorSizeArr.colSize.length; i++) {
            if (colorSizeArr.colSize[i].specificId == specificId) {
                return colorSizeArr.colSize[i].amount;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    function DrawAmountDD(maxAmount) {
        var max = parseInt(maxAmount) > parseInt(maxShowAmount) ? maxShowAmount : maxAmount;
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            html += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
        }
        $("#amountDD").html(html);

    }
</script>
```

Update

I have not figured out exatcly why Internet Explorer 7 crashes on some computers. Any way the code above had not any thing to do with it. It was much more simpler. The browser crashed when clicking on a select-box with only one option. Like this:

```
<select id="amountDD">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

I found some info on this link where it says that the single option should have a selected attribute as well but it does seems to crash for us with out the attribute.

http://www.akselvoll.net/2007/08/ie7-crashes-when-clicking-on-drop-down.html

Comment: Can you post 'GetAmountById' function as well?

Comment: Also - can you explain what you mean by crash? your screenshot shows the site but not the error.

Comment: The browers totally crashes but not on my machines.

Comment: I forgot to post the url. Please let me know if anybodyes IE7 crash when touching the size and color selectbox. Need more clues. You can try it live here: http://velour.se/collection/women/tops/eloise

Comment: So this dies on every XP machine EXCEPT for your machines? Did you debug the JS, adding in alerts and whatnot for every variable you're using? Also, there's no definition of `maxShowAmount` and `GetAmountById` as KevinP said. Finally, can you give the option tags that are inside of the select?

Comment: Not sure how common the crash is yet. Only had two reports of failure. I have uploaded a new version to the live web site, I post this soon above here along with the missing variables. I will ask those people who got the crashes to try again.

Comment: @jesperlind: take a close look at `BindColorDD()`: `html += "<option value'" + arr[i] + "'>" + arr[i] + "</option>"`. That is not valid markup.

Comment: Do you by any chance use CSS expressions on the HTML element(s) in question? They are known to crash IE in (lot of) certain circumstances.

Comment: can you post a link to the site so we can try it out in order to reproduce? or maybe post the entire html/js to pastebin.com

Comment: @Crescent-fresh: Good catch! I have fixed the error on the live site.

Comment: @QAZ: I have posted the link in the fourth comment from the top in this thread. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Still no progress. Now I suspect it has to do with Single Sign On on my HP ProtectTools Security. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/63216546-9289-4345-898c-860d02db7357

Comment: Or this: http://www.akselvoll.net/2007/08/ie7-crashes-when-clicking-on-drop-down.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this my self as best as I can. If some body has a more detailed answer please add in and I will mark that one as accepted instead.

Internet Explorer 7 seems to crash on under some circumstances due to a bug in the browser or the system. The machines we had issues with were from HP running Vista. Perhaps the Vender had installed something disturbing the browser like the "Sign On on my HP ProtectTools Security" as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/63216546-9289-4345-898c-860d02db7357

Other possibillites are described here: http://www.akselvoll.net/2007/08/ie7-crashes-when-clicking-on-drop-down.html

Easy fix is to upgrade Internet Explorer to version 8.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need for the `javascript:` prefix in your mark up.  The handler will expect that it's javascript code and I'm surprised that any browsers actually parse it.  Generally you see it as a protocol tag in an `href` attribute and, even that's not a good way to handle it.  Second, the parameter to the function is a reference to the DOM element (select) whose value attribute may or may not be well supported.  There's a good reference for HTML/Javascript DOM at http://www.w3schools.com.  See the [Select](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp) reference there. To get the value you may want to do `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`.  Third, it would probably be better all around to add the handler via javascript.

```
var select = document.getElementById( 'sizeDD' );
select.onchange = function() { sizeChange(select); };
```

Or since I see now that you are using jQuery:

```
$('sizeDD').change( sizeChange );
```

Comment: I don't mind the downvote so much, but perhaps you might want to explain what I've gotten wrong.  I'm always happy to learn when I'm mistaken.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980 See the `value` attribute. Test it here: http://jsbin.com/ecuni. (Note that `selectedIndex` is sound and works well across browsers). (Also thanks for not freaking out about the downvote. Have gotten burned recently when DV'ing + commenting).

Comment: Interesting to learn -- I didn't check the spec, but my more often used resource at w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

I hope by "crash" you mean "the JavaScript doesn't work",  not "Internet Explorer crashes."  If it's just the page, you can usually see the error by clicking "error on page" in the status bar.
Also, try some classic JavaScript debugging - comment out blocks of the function one at a time until you find the block that crashes it, then narrow it down to the line.

Comment: I mean a total crash. I have seen it on a customer laptop. It happens every time on two of their computers. I have asked them to disable all addons and enpty cache but still.

There is not js-errors. I have tried i alla broswers on ceveral machines. My IE7 does not crash. Only the customers.